get_theme_file_uri does not work for scripts…
Im trying to turn a web template into a static Wordpress theme and get_theme_file_uri resolves in the url/the files instead of wp-content/themes/thetheme/js/plugins/swiper.min.js
so instead of looking for the file here:
http://learning-test.local/wp-content/themes/TERAFORMED/js/plugins/swiper.min.js
it looks for the file here:
http://learning-test.local/js/plugins/swiper.min.js
However when i log it in the debug file i see it resolves to http://learning-test.local/wp-content/themes/TERAFORMED/js/plugins/swiper.min.js
it also doesn’t work on a hosting…
I am speechless this looks impossible to be happening according to chatgpt and claude(im new to wordpress development)
The url on which this is happening: zanixa.merchsolution.net
I tried everything I know, i double checked the urls I added debuging and im looking at the debug file and i can't believe what im seeing,  the error log logs the right url but the url is wrong in the browser...
PS: My only theory is that it should be something in the js file but i don't see anything wrong there
here is my theme:
https://github.com/apexdigitalreaper/apex-digital-theme/tree/main/teraformed

Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem. Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem?

I installed your theme locally on my machine and I can call the get_theme_file_uri() function without any issues. I get the correct path to http://localhost/wp-content/themes/teraformed/js/plugins/swiper.min.js.
So I guess your issue has something to do with either your .htaccess or your webserver configuration. I hope this helps.

is it possible that both the live and the local installs have the same .htaccess issue? I have another theme that im working on that works fine, same out of the box installation with some basic html css and js and everything is enqueued the same way and it works...

code
BEGIN WordPress
The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

END WordPress
here is my .htaccess
